# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, gcc

I'm trying to compile my cross-platform OpenGL application on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit running inside a VirtualBox. However it always fails with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`.

I've googled the issue extensively and tried installing every package mentioned as a solution, even manually created symbolic links a couple times, etc... Basically I've tried any solution I could find. Any more ideas? What am I missing?

Output of `locate libGL`:

```
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.13
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.13.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.13
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.13.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGL.la
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX_nvidia.so.375.66
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0
/var/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/lib/libGL.so.1
```

(Clearly the system has more than enough libGL to choose from, yet it still won't find it.)

Comment: Run the linker using `strace -ffo linker <linker-command-line>` and then grep `linker*` files for `libGL` to see in which directories it looks for `libGL`·

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Seems like it's only looking for `libGL.a` and not `libGL.so`. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: Show the complete linker command line.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `gcc libs/gl3w.c src/*.c -o foo.exe -Ilibs/include -Llibs/lib -static -pedantic-errors -lglfw3 -lGL -Os` Does Ubuntu just not like statically linked GL programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `-static` command line switch prevents it from linking to shared libraries.

In the linker command line replace `-lGL` with `-Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -static` to only link `-lGL` dynamically.

Comment: Does this mean I will have to ship an .dll with my application or is it safe to assume most systems will already have one available?

Comment: @Wingblade You probably want to assume that the target system already has OpenGL libraries installed. It is normally the job of the user to install the graphics driver required for their GPU.

Comment: Sweet, I had no idea you could pick and choose static/dynamic linkage. `lGL` is now successfully found!

Comment: @Wingblade And it does not seem that production OpenGL libraries can be linked statically. I can be wrong though.

Comment: @Wingblade: In Linux libGL is not just a library, it's actually where the a part of the userspace of the GPU drivers live (this is in accordance with the Linux Standards Base and the Linux OpenGL ABI as specified by Khronos). Which in essence means that you **must not** link libGL statically and in fact that there will never be a statically linkable version of libGL around. There are statically linkable OpenGL implementations available, but these will never be GPU accelerated and always be named something other than libGL.