# Can I force the compiler to put my shared libraries in the binary as well?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, g++, shared-libraries

I did made a OpenGL program using glfw3, glm, opengl and glut. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and the G++ compiler. I compile it like this:

```
g++ -o main Main.cpp FastNoise.cpp shader.cpp texture.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 
-lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor -lGLEW
```

Please note that this is a older compile command I did made as I'm currently not able to get to my working pc. I tried to execute the resulting main on a different Linux System and it told me it failed due missing shared libraries. Is there some easy way I can fix this? I have read I need to statically link my libraries but I don't know where they are located. I have only got them like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgle...
```

Comment: [Flatpak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak)?  [Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be static linkable versions of GLU, glfw and GLEW available. **Never** statically link GL or any of the X11 stuff. There's a simple reason for that: libGL.so actually contains part of the GPU drivers, so to work it must be match the version of the kernel modules and the X server modules. Hence it must be linked dynamically. And since libGL.so also contains all the GLX stuff, which interacts with X11 libraries, those X11 libraries must be linked dynamically as well.

Luckily the OpenGL/GLX/X11 library requirements are written down in Linux-Software-Base/Desktop, so on any system that runs a X11 based desktop this stuff is available.

Comment: Thanks! What should I look for to get those libraries as static libraries? Can I do with a compiler flag or are these special versions? I have read I need to link to their absolute path so they get static but I'm neither quite sure how I exactly need to link this nor where I can get the absolute path of them.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: A question quite similar to your's was asked a few days ago. See this answer which explains how to link all static except for selected libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789712/524368

Comment: It seems like I just did it. I did download the source code for GLEW and glfw and then I typed `cmake` and `make` respectively and copied the .a files to the directory of my application. Then I compiled like this `g++ -o main Main.cpp FastNoise.cpp shader.cpp texture.cpp libglfw3.a libGLEW.a -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor ` and I could run it on a UbuntuVM without any problems. Thank you very much!